# create dynamic growing width for content

Tags: css, html

Hello I know there is alot of questions about dynamic width for contents.. but this specific question I couldn't find a good answer for.

I have the following setup for my website ( some pages )

```
         +--------------+---------------------------------+
     |              |                                 |
     |  Sidebar     |       Content                   |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     |              |                                 |
     +--------------+---------------------------------+
```

And the total width is 980px

But on some of these pages I don't use a sidebar so there is blank space on the left.. how can I solve this by letting the content page flow to the left when there is no sidebar?

```
     +--------------+---------------------------------+
     |                                                |
     |                      Content                   |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     |                                                |
     +--------------+---------------------------------+
```

I have the following html structure

I gave both the aside and content divs a fixed width and the aside has a float left and the content a float right.

Is there a good easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#content{overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: not working.. the content goes left and the sidebar is under it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9vJw/4/)** that shows two cases: one with a sidebar and one without it.

One thing to remember is, that a `display: block` property makes an element go with all of the available width, despite the content. And that's what `.content` does - the `float: left` makes it appear right next to the sidebar if present, and fills all available space.

### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: rgb(255, 176, 176); /* Light Red */
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(148, 148, 255); /* Light Blue */

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work somehow.. If i make a structure only test setup it works but when implementing in my website it doesn't work.

Comment: Everything can be fixed, this layout is fairly simple and not complicated. Try to give us a sample of a not working layout and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: But the site isn't implementing my idea at all. And why do you call it a "sandbox" exactly?

Comment: sorry that was the old version I have pushed the new version now. does the name matter for the code?